# insert or replace into table2 from table1

Tags: mysql, insert

I'd like to use the 'insert into' mysql command to move table1 contents to table2, but table2 may have the 'same' primary keys.  I want to replace the table2's record (that have the same primary key) with table1's record when the insert statement is executed.  Can I use 'or replace' to make this happen?

Comment: `duplicate primary keys` is somewhat of an oxymoron...

Comment: @MarcB I think he means duplicated with Table 1's Primary keys

Comment: I will 'same' instead of duplicate to respect the English language.

Comment: @MarcB when two tables are being merged, it's quite plain that there may be duplicated values in the primary key column, no? This is exactly what `ON DUPLICATE KEY` exists for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an INSERT ... SELECT with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
  SELECT * FROM table1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table2.field1 = table1.field1
```

*note* using * for brevity, but in the update clause you *must* specify the fields individually, and *should* do so in the insert and select clauses as well.

Comment: So what does mysql do when you try to insert 'like' primary keys in each table?  Does it throw an error?

Comment: When you say "like", you mean exact duplicates? Then usually yes; but it depends on what mode your server is in. The "ON DUPLICATE KEY" clause can circumvent that error by telling the server to perform the update instead of throwing the error.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this (without knowing your exact schema this can only be an example)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_a (a,b,c)
SELECT a,b,c FROM tbl_b 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = tbl_b.b, c = tbl_b.c
```

From the docs for [`INSERT on DUPLICATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed

Answer (score 0):

If the primary keys in table2 that are duplicates of keys in table1 are not referred to by foreign keys elsewhere, the easiest way is to use [REPLACE ... INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html):

"REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted."

So, you'd do something like this:

```
REPLACE INTO table2 (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c FROM table1;
```

It will sort out the keys for you, so any rows in `table2` with the same ID as a row in `table1` are overwritten by `table1`'s row data.

Comment: This really depends on whether there are foreign keys in use here - if there are and they are using cascade delete - then good by associated data ...this is because `replace ... into` does a delete then an insert